# Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [XXX] on this ManagedType [unknown]

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria-api, hibernate-5.x, criteriaquery

I have this entity with its ID defined in Identifiable class.

InventoryLoad has InventoryLoadID as its PK

```
public class InventoryLoad extends AbstractIdentifiable<InventoryLoadId> implements Auditable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "inventoryLoad")
    private Set<InventorySubLoad> inventorySubLoads = Sets.newLinkedHashSet();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "stoloc", referencedColumnName = "stoloc"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "wh_id", referencedColumnName = "wh_id")
    })
    private Location location;

    @Column(name = "lodwgt")
    private Double loadWeight;

    @Column(name = "prmflg")
    private Boolean permanentLoadSubFlag;
}
```

This is the ID for above class

```
@Embeddable
public class InventoryLoadId extends AbstractIdentifiableId {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Column(name = "lodnum")
    private String loadNumber;

    // some another code below
}
```

I am using Criteria builder to get to the column of ID class.

To get this using Path to get the path of inventoryid that is PK.

```
Session session = new HibernateTools().getSession();

CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);

Root<InventoryLoad> inventoryLoadRoot = criteriaQuery.from(InventoryLoad.class);
Path<InventoryLoadId> inventoryLoadIdPath = inventoryLoadRoot.get("id");
criteriaQuery.multiselect(inventoryLoadIdPath.get("loadNumber"),
```

Getting this error

`Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [loadNumber] on this ManagedType [unknown]`

Comment: You are pvery surely missing `@Entity`

Comment: I have just pasted the snippets of code.
Entity tag is present.

Answer (score 0):

Criteria in hibernate work fine with JPA static metamodel. Try to use it

```
@Embeddable
public class InventoryLoadId extends AbstractIdentifiableId {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "lodnum")
    private String loadNumber;

}

@Generated(value = "org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor")
@StaticMetamodel(InventoryLoadId.class)
public abstract class InventoryLoadId_ {

    public static volatile SingularAttribute<InventoryLoadId, String> loadNumber;

}
```

```
Session session = new HibernateTools().getSession();
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

// create the query
CriteriaQuery<InventoryLoadId> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(InventoryLoadId.class);

// set the root class
Root<InventoryLoadId> inventoryLoadRoot = query.from(InventoryLoadId.class);

query.multiselect(inventoryLoadRoot.get(InventoryLoadId_.loadNumber).alias("loadNumber"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
But I am getting compilation errors.